# How to prevent html code from being written to the "database"?

Tags: php, json, database, smile

The working principle of my code is the following: if in the input line there are have such  smileys (":)", ":(") then you need to replace them with pictures. Here's how I do it:

```
$smile = array(":)", ":(");
$grafic = array("<img src = './image/Smile.png' alt='Smile' align='middle'>",
    "<img src = './image/Sad.png' alt='Smile' align='middle'>");    
$new_message = str_replace($smile, $grafic, $message);

$file = "../data/messages.json";
$json_content = json_decode(file_get_contents($file), true);

if (!empty($new_message)) {
    $json_content[] = array("time" => $time, "user" => $user, "message"  => $new_message);
    file_put_contents($file, json_encode($json_content, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT));
}
```

But then, I have to write down the already changed string I write in the "database" (`json` file) and there we can see following:

```
[
    {
        "time": "1499985376",
        "user": "Max",
        "message": "Hello <img src = '.\/image\/Smile.png' alt='Smile' align='middle'>"
    }
]
```

How can I write a word "smile" or "sad" instead of the `HTML` tags?

Comment: Why don't you keep it persisted in the raw format, or some fixed up version of same (e.g. `:smile:`) and then deal with converting if and when you need to show it as HTML?

Comment: @tadman How i can do that?

Comment: Step 1: Convert `:)` to whatever notation you want. Step 2: Save it. Step 3: Write another function to convert that to HTML.

Answer (score 0):

1. Just create a new variable and save the message before you make the
   changes, like: `$rawMessage = $message;`.
2. Then use the `$rawMessage` to save the message to the database.

Comment: But now i have one little problem: you see,  after I wrote the data to a file, then I need to get them from the file and display them on the screen. But there smileys are ":)". Tell me, is it possible to correct them somehow to pictures without another "operation" with replacing smileys for pictures?

Comment: You could write both messages to the file. You could also write only the raw message to the file and every time you load the file replace the smileys. The second approach is the widely used one.